# Appcelerator CLI fails to launch Android App after updating from 8.2.0.GA to 9.0.X.GA SDK

Tags: android, node.js, titanium, appcelerator

I have an app in production since 2015 and I've been updated it many times with different Titanium SDK versions.

Right now I need to update it again and I would like to use the latest Titanium SDK 9.0.2, but for some reason it fails to launch on Android, iOS works fine. The app builds correctly but it doesn't install it into the device and it hangs at launch time. The last console message that it shows it's this:

```
[INFO]  App successfully installed
[INFO]  Starting app: com.xxx.xxx/.xxxActivity (I hided the name)
[ERROR] Application failed to launch

The current timeout is set to 120000 ms
You can increase this timeout by running: titanium.js config android.appStartTimeout <timeout ms>
```

It says that the app is successfully installed but it doesn't. I've increased the timeout like it says to double that time and the result it's the same.

If I run the exact same app with 8.2.0.GA it works with no problems.

I'm using an Android device (Xiaomi Mi A2 Lite) with Android 9 on MacOS 10.14.6. Here is my configuration:

```
 ──────────────────┤   Check Environment   ├─────────────────── 

Node.js
  ✓  node               installed (v10.13.0)
  ✓  npm                installed (v6.4.1)

Titanium CLI
  ★  cli                new version v5.2.2 available (currently v5.1.1)

Titanium CLI Dependencies
  ✓  acs                up-to-date (v2.1.0)
  ✓  alloy              up-to-date (v1.13.9)
  ✓  appc-cli-titanium  up-to-date (v4.4.26)
  ✓  appc-inquirer      up-to-date (v0.1.10)
  ✓  appc-logger        up-to-date (v1.1.27)
  ✓  appc-platform-sdk  up-to-date (v3.1.0)
  ✓  appcd              up-to-date (v1.1.3)
  ✓  arrow              up-to-date (v3.2.12)
  ✓  async              up-to-date (v1.5.2)
  ✓  chalk              up-to-date (v1.1.3)
  ✓  char-spinner       up-to-date (v1.0.1)
  ✓  columnify          up-to-date (v1.5.4)
  ✓  commander          up-to-date (v2.9.0)
  ✓  debug              up-to-date (v2.6.9)
  ✓  ejs                up-to-date (v2.6.1)
  ✓  fields             up-to-date (v0.1.24)
  ✓  fs-extra           up-to-date (v0.26.7)
  ✓  inquirer           up-to-date (v0.11.4)
  ✓  ip                 up-to-date (v1.1.5)
  ✓  jwt-simple         up-to-date (v0.3.1)
  ✓  lodash             up-to-date (v3.10.1)
  ✓  node-appc          up-to-date (v0.2.49)
  ✓  node-forge         up-to-date (v0.6.49)
  ✓  node-ios-device    up-to-date (v1.7.1)
  ✓  npm-conf           up-to-date (v1.1.3)
  ✓  pac-proxy-agent    up-to-date (v2.0.2)
  ✓  plural             up-to-date (v0.2.1)
  ✓  progress           up-to-date (v1.1.8)
  ✓  recursive-readdir  up-to-date (v2.2.2)
  ✓  request            up-to-date (v2.88.0)
  ✓  retire             up-to-date (v1.6.3)
  ✓  semver             up-to-date (v5.7.0)
  ✓  tar                up-to-date (v4.4.8)
  ✓  tiapp.xml          up-to-date (v0.2.2)
  ✓  titanium           up-to-date (v5.1.1)
  ✓  version-bump-prompt up-to-date (v3.1.2)
  ✓  which              up-to-date (v1.3.1)
  ✓  wrench             up-to-date (v1.5.9)

Titanium SDK
  ✓  latest sdk         installed (v9.0.2.GA)
  ✓  selected sdk       up-to-date (v9.0.2.GA)

Mac OS X Environment
  ✓  CLI Tools          installed

iOS Environment
  ✓  Xcode              installed (11.3.1)
  ✓  iOS SDK            installed (13.2.2)
  ✓  WWDR cert          installed
  ✓  developer cert     installed (3 found)
  ✓  distribution cert  installed (5 found)
  ✓  dev provisioning   installed (21 found)
  ✓  dist provisioning  installed (14 found)

Android Environment
  ✓  sdk                installed (/Users/luiscript/android-sdk)
  ✓  tools              installed (v25.2.5)
  ✓  platform tools     installed (v29.0.6)
  ✓  build tools        installed (v29.0.3)
  ✓  adb                installed /Users/luiscript/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb
  ✕  android            "android" executable not found; please reinstall Android SDK
  ✓  emulator           installed /Users/luiscript/android-sdk/tools/emulator
  ✓  mksdcard           installed /Users/luiscript/android-sdk/tools/mksdcard
  ✓  zipalign           installed /Users/luiscript/android-sdk/build-tools/29.0.3/zipalign
  ✓  aapt               installed /Users/luiscript/android-sdk/build-tools/29.0.3/aapt
  ✓  aidl               installed /Users/luiscript/android-sdk/build-tools/29.0.3/aidl
  ✓  targets            installed (9 found)
  ✓  avds               installed (8 found)
  ✓  ndk                installed (15.1.4119039)
  ✓  ndk-build          installed (/Users/luiscript/android-ndk-r15b/ndk-build)

Java Development Kit
  ✓  jdk                installed (v1.8.0)
  ✓  java               installed /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
  ✓  javac              installed /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/javac
  ✓  keytool            installed /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/keytool
  ✓  jarsigner          installed /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/jarsigner

Intel® Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (HAXM)
  ✓  compatible         
  !  installed          not found; install HAXM to use Android x86 emulator

Network
  ✓  online             
  -  no proxy server configured 
  ✓  Network connection test 
  ✓  Java-based connection test 

Directory Permissions
  ✓  home directory     
  ✓  titanium config directory 
  ✓  titanium sdk install directory 
  ✓  temp directory
```

I've tried different versions of node without success. For now I have given up and I think I will work with 8.2.0.GA. because is the latest version that works for me that supports iOS 13 and Android 10.

It's weird because if I create a fresh new app it works and installs correctly and I've noticed that the new app has this property in the tiapp.xml file:

`<property name="appc-app-id" type="string">XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</property>`

and my current app doesn't have that tag, I don't know if that has something to do with it.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: could your try 8.3.1.GA, that is the latest in the 8.x branch. Also compile with `-l trace` to see some more output. `adb logcat` would be another option to check (will be alot of output, make sure to watch the start process and check for any errors). Then it would be interesting to know if you have any code running before `onOpen` that could block the launch. The `appc-app-id` is used when you compile using `appc` cli. It is the ID that is registered insidet the appc backend. If you continue to use `ti` cli you can remove that

Comment: 8.3.1.GA worked as expected, I'm glad that there was a newer versión than 8.2.0.GA. Also I did a `-l trace` with 9.0.2.GA and it didn't throw me anything useful. I believe `onOpen` is used with Alloy right? I'm using Titanium Classic project. With `adb logcat` I'm still waiting to finish, that was crazy unreadable, but I inspected the output looking for something without finding any error…Either way, thank you so much for your help.

Comment: you can use `addEventListener("open", clb)` in a Classic app. But it should also be slow in 8.x. App start changed in 9 and especially on Android it will be faster at the end (and compiling!). The hard way to check where it actually is stopping: add a lot of console.log's to see up to which place you are going. Or use https://github.com/m1ga/from_zero_to_app/blob/master/chrome_safari_devtools.md to step through your code. There are different ways to find the culprit but without code it is complicated :) Try to install a dist build, too! All my transitions from 8->9 went very smoothly.

Comment: `adb logcat`: I clean my console all the time up to the last moment before starting the app. Then I'll wait a few seconds (here a bit after nothing happens) and kill the process. So you don't have too much output and you are close to an error if it is in the log

Comment: I don't think that console.log will help because the app doesn't install on the phone, even when the console says that it was successfully installed. I will try everything that you suggest… BTW I follow you on github since long time ago, glad to see you here too.

Comment: Nice, hope I can help here too :) If it doesn't install you could do that manually. But according to the log it should be on the device. Maybe some tiapp.xml `<application>` setting is used now because of the gradle support, that is mixing up the launch intent `intent-filter`, check `build/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` if you see a `intent-filter`  with main and launch.

Comment: I know "according to the log" it should, but I'm sure it doesn't install, I can copy the apk manually, but for development that sucks. Manifest has `intent filter` with main and launcher. For now I would stuck with 8.3.1, but eventually I will need to upgrade. Thanks again :(

Comment: ok, you can also join tislack.org. A bit better/quicker to reply/chat there!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the problem was, but I updated to MacOS Catalina and Xcode 11.5 and now everything is working fine without any change.